# Do we need a a Clue and a Cluedo tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Can these tags be consolidated? Or is there enough value in differentiating the US and Uk versions?

Comment: Blame me for that... I tagged my question with both names and I assume I created the clue tag in the process.

Answer (score 6):

I think we should use a tag synonym.  I assume the differences are very minor.  [They have a post about this on the StackOverflow Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/).  Unfortunately, we need some users with 1,000 reputation before we can get those set up ourselves, but the Stack Exchange team can probably do it for us.

Comment: We have some users with 1000 rep now, although this number will likely start growing much faster when the Public Beta starts in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: You need at least 2500 rep to create tag synonyms... so those of us with over 1000 can't do it yet.

Comment: @Brian Campbell Yeah, I'm not sure why I said 1,000.  It is 2,500.

Comment: @Brian: I see you got tired of waiting until you had 2500 rep and just removed the clue tag.

Comment: @Powerlord Yep, was just looking for any tag cleanup that needed to be done and did that. I will add the tag synonym as soon as I have enough rep; I was thinking that since `cluedo` already had two tagged questions, and is the original name, I'd go with that as the official tag and `clue` as the synonym.

Answer (score 3):

It's a funny one, but no, they shouldn't be consolidated.

I wasn't even aware Cluedo went by a different name in the US - I doubt many other Brits would either.

EDIT: A tag synonym would be a good fix (although it might still cause confusion to some), but the question is, what should be the 'main' name. The original name, or the US name?

Comment: Upvote for the edit; they should be consolidated, as they're the same game, but as a synonym. Of course, how do we pick which one to use; do we standardize on British spelling, American spelling, or always pick the original name if they differ? I asked about this on bicycles.se a few days ago, and it seems that tag synonyms with the US spelling are preferred: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/165/american-vs-british-english-in-tags

Comment: Cluedo goes by a different name in the US because we don't have [Ludo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludo_%28board_game%29) over here, and thus the parody of its name was lost on us uncultured Yankees. ;)

Comment: @Powerlord Didn't even realise it was a parody!

Comment: Up-vote for the edit.  I'm on the U.S. side, and never realized that "Clue" was actually an alternate name made just for us.  We should definitely keep it around.  Deciding which is the "primary" tag may be tricky, though.