# 2500 rep for suggesting tag synonyms?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms

I've recently gone over 2500 rep, and [according to the privileges page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), have enough rep to suggest tag synonyms. Since we've [had a discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/do-we-need-a-a-clue-and-a-cluedo-tag) about the `clue` vs. `cluedo` tags, and decided that a synonym is probably the best way to deal with it, I tried creating a `clue` synonym for the `cluedo` tag. However, when I did so, I received an error message: "**You are not allowed to propose a tag synonym!**"; on the same page, it says "Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 10 or more on the tag, can **suggest** and **vote on** tag synonyms."

Is this a bug? Why can't I create this synonym?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have a total answer score of 10 or more on either or both of the tags?

Comment: @Erik Oops, missed that half of the sentence. I figured that synonyms would be a moderation type cleanup feature that anyone with enough rep could do, not just those with a high enough rep in the given tag. Too bad I can't also tag this question as status-bydesign.

Comment: The assumption is if you have enough score or are ranked high enough in the tag, you probably know enough about it to be editing the tag wiki

Comment: this used to be true, but we had some very high profile tag merge screwups in the past, and there is no real undo path for those.