# "Clue" tag rearing its ugly head

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we need a a Clue and a Cluedo tag](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/do-we-need-a-a-clue-and-a-cluedo-tag)

There's [a question with the 'Clue' tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7638/would-a-clockwise-turn-order-affect-the-strategy-or-gameplay-in-clue-in-a-meanin) now. This has some history: we [discussed this a long time ago](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/do-we-need-a-a-clue-and-a-cluedo-tag) and decided that once we would be able to, we would make 'Clue' and 'Cluedo' synonyms. At some point [Brian C](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/112/brian-campbell) deleted the 'Clue' tag, but it seems to have arisen again. I tried proposing a synonym, but I don't have the requisite 5 rep in either tag. Could a mod please make the synonym?

Comment: Synonym created. Closing as a duplicate to avoid splitting the discussion.